# How do I determine which platform version is required?

Tags: continuous-integration, version-detection, platform-specific

This frequently comes up: I've built software, and possibly used some new language / platform / standard library features that are available on some version (say, Java 1.6.10 or PHP 5.2) upwards, but of course I can't exactly remember. I'm only sure that it runs at least on the version I'm using (which is typically the newest version available), but it might well run on a bit older version too.

Going manually through the code, keeping a list and comparing it with platform release notes obviously isn't very sophisticated option. Is there a way to automatically do this (aside from baking your own version-checker parser)? Personally I'm interested in at least the following languages, but please add freely:

- Java
- Python
- PHP
- C++ (and maybe C)
- add your favorite.

Simply testing at the older versions is a brute force approach, and it has the advantage that you'll know whether the code actually *works*, not merely that it *should* work. But it can be tedious, so I'm still interested in some kind of automata that goes through the source and checks which platform features are being used.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous integration's Build Automation is the first thing that comes to mind. If you're testing against different machines, you'll discover which version breaks your code.